# deity / divinity / god

Tags: word-usage, translation, religion

I'm translating some Buddhist texts to English and I'm wondering if there are any subtle differences in usage between the words **deity**, **divinity**, and **god** (in the lower case sense)?

What is the word for their *"earthly" counterpart* (by which I mean "natural being" or "ordinary people")?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, [divinity for one is delicious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divinity_(confectionery)). I haven’t tasted the other two, though. :)

Comment: _Mortal_ or _man_ is often used in contrast to _god._

Comment: In general English I would say no, there might be technical difference used in specific religions where the distinction matters. Especially tricky for Buddism presumably

Comment: There is also some differences in etymology. God comes from old English while on the other hand Deity has a Latin background and comes from Deus.

Comment: @Jasper: I did struggle about choosing between your answer and Greg's. Yours was very useful, particularly in making a distinction between *god* and *deity* in the context of Buddhism. On the other hand, Greg gave specific examples on the usage of those words and a word for the "earthly counterpart" of gods. Really, these two answers complement each other: Greg's answer is more comprehensive while yours is more pertinent. I would have accepted both if I were able to. Since the quality of the two answers are so close, I chose Greg's because he had posted the answer earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we make much distinction in common speech between "a deity" "a divinity" and "a god," although "a divinity" is rather rare and leaves me, at least, with the feeling you're speaking of something vague. "There is a divinity that shapes our ends . . ." is probably the best-known use of it. Deity seems a bit more formal than "god."

The earthly manifestation of a god is sometimes called an *incarnation.*

The earthly counterparts you're looking for are probably "mortals." "The gods do not often speak plainly to mortals."

Answer (score 3):

In Buddhist texts in the English language, *god* refers to a being in the god realm, the other realms being the demigod realm, the human realm, the animal realm, the hungry ghost realm, and the hell realm. *Deity* usually refers to bodhisattvas in Mahayana. *Divinity* is not usually used.

Answer (score 1):

Deity is something -Creatures usually have distant features from human, you can say not human at all- that have been worshiped by peoples usually for hired like to give safety, flourishing the land, etc. The divinity is creature that has divine properties, the holy one, or the one that has freed from filthiness. The last creature is God the one that have been accused by all creature as a suspect that create the world, The Creator. Well, God also can defined as the creature that play a part in the creation of the world, or have big role deciding human or humanity fates.

The differences off all this creatures is the mortality feature and the effect they have for human. Divinity is creature that have a good alignment, many describe holy as good, but is not immortal. Divinity can be slayed or reincarnate. Deity is creature that have abilities that exceed human their behavior and affinity is not generalized as good or bad and they are not immortal. Deity can meet their end. The last is God, the immortal creature that known for their tremendous infinite power.

Comment: Do you have a source for these definitions?